# Prove if $a,b,c$ are integers and $9\mid a^2+b^2+c^2$ then $9\mid a^2-b^2$ or $9\mid a^2-c^2$ or $9\mid b^2-c^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Attempting to help a non-math major answer this question. Unsure why the problem allows the option for "$9\mid a^2-b^2$ or $9\mid a^2-c^2$ or $9\mid b^2-c^2$".

Also we have to prove without using Fibonacci sequence unless we prove with a 1-1 correspondence.

Comment: I can’t see any clear connection with Fibonacci numbers, so I’ve replaced that tag with a more appropriate one.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to notice that when you square an integer, you get a multiple of $9$, or you get $1$, $4$, or $7$ more than a multiple of $9$. Then think about how you can add three such numbers to get a multiple of $9$, and show that no matter how you do it, two of the numbers must be in the same class.